# Combining multiple Java Swing applications into one

Tags: java, swing

Currently I have one application that creates four new process. The four processes that are created create a JFrame, display a video on a AWT Canvas, and run some rendering processes.

My question is, if there is anyway for me to instead of having four separate JFrames, combine all of them into one JFrame. Ideally have something like a JTabbedPanel that would switch from displaying each process.

They must stay in different processes.

Versions: 
Java 1.8

Comment: All JFrames have a content pane. A content pane is simply a JPanel, So there is no reason you can't add the JPanel that you create for each process to a JTabbedPane.

Comment: Swing has to be done from the same thread (the AWT EDT), so not directly. You could have one with a JFrame and tell the others, through your favourite IPC mechanism, where and when to show their borderless windows. May be difficult to get working seamlessly depending on platform. Other than that, it's digging into implementation-speffic stuff.

Comment: @camickr I'm talking about separate processes here. The JPanel in one application has no idea of the existence of the JPanel in the other applications. I have attempted to see if swing has any implementation to talk to out of process frames, or if there was a third party library that might make this problem a bit more simple.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline That's line up with the research I have been doing. Was hoping someone out there might have an easier way to implement something like this.

Comment: Well, I don't know what a "process" means to you. Is it simply code executing in a separate Thread so it doesn't block the EDT of the main frame? I don't know if you expect the "process" to execute in the background, or whether is should stop/start as you switch tabs. All I was stating is that when you create a JFrame you add components to the frame and that is no different then adding components to a tabbed pane. Each tab is independent of the other tabs. The concern is that the AWT Canvas class doesn't always play nice when used in a Swing application.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will be able to do something like that. The best approach would be performing whatever background tasks you need to perform on the separate processes and then stream the result (through any means) into the application containing JFrame with tabs containing UI for each process. In your case - that would each process performing video rendering & then streaming result into the process containing JFrame with all related UI.

Comment: Although if all of your mentioned processes are Java applications written by you - I'm not sure why wouldn't you simply get rid of having separate processes and simply render video in separate threads within one Java application, unless you have some specific hard limitations on paralleled rendering within single JVM or something else.

Comment: @MikleGarin There are JVM limitations. The application will crash about 50% of the time if they are all running in the thread, the solution to this was putting them in different threads. Now I'm working on how to manage the different frames to ideally create what looks to be one application. If that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question completely, but have you thought about using JInternalFrames? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html